# IQueryable Casting error at "Select new"

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
 IQueryable<GRNDetail> selectedResults = from c in InventoryContext.GRNDetails
                              where c.ProductID == pro.ProductID && (c.Quantity - c.SoldQuantity > 0 || c.SoldQuantity.Value.Equals(null))
                              select new
                              {
                                  c.GRNDetailID,
                                  c.GRNID,
                                  c.Product,
                                  c.ProductID,
                                  c.PurchaseOrderDetail,
                                  c.PurchaseOrderDetailID,

                                  c.Quantity,
                                  c.SoldQuantity,
                                  c.Tax,
                                  c.TaxRate,
                                  c.Total,
                                  c.UnitPrice, 
                                  SaleQty = (c.Quantity - c.SoldQuantity)
                              };
```

Comment: You are trying to put an anonymous type into a GRNDetail, try select new GRNDetail {prop1 = value1, prop2 = value2}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing your type : GRNDetail in the select :
`select new GRNDetail`

Edit : 
Alternatively use `Select c` ; to bring back the entire object. Or also you can create a custom type if you only want certain items.

you can create a custom Type like this : with your SaleQty (set to currency or double or whatever datatype suits your needs : And use this for your result :

```
 public class GRNDetailResults
    {
        public int GRNDetailID { get; set; }

        public int GRNID { get; set; }

        etc ....

        public double SaleQty { get; set; }
```

E.g

```
IQueryable<GRNDetailResults> selectedResults = from c in InventoryContext.GRNDetails
                              where c.ProductID == pro.ProductID && (c.Quantity - c.SoldQuantity > 0 || c.SoldQuantity.Value.Equals(null))
                              select new GRNDetailResults
                              {
                                 GRNDetailID = c.GRNDetailID,
                                  GRNID  =c.GRNID, 
                                   etc ...
                                  SaleQty = (c.Quantity - c.SoldQuantity)
                              };
```

Comment: If `GRNDetail` is generated by EF, one can't project to that

Comment: Yes if GRNDetail is not a custome type and is generated by EF ,  you can use Select c; to bring back the entire object. Or alternatively create a custom type if you only want certain items.

Comment: I need to get "(c.Quantity - c.SoldQuantity)" this value field also as an additional field and set this result to a "datagrid view" in wpf  Im still stuck here.. can any one give me a solution please?

Comment: Did you try creating your own custom type ? Ive added some sample code above so you cans see what i mean ...